# Как в Qt в блок VALUES( ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) вместо значений вставить подзапрос SELECT

Tags: sql, qt, postgresql

Возможно ли написать запрос таким образом, чтобы в запросе INSERT в блоке VALUES вместо значений был подзапрос SELECT? 
Пример:

Такой вариант использую в Qt для отправки запроса пачками QSqlQuery::execBatch()

```
INSERT INTO LIQ_METER_VALUES ( LIQ_METER_SN, LIQ_METER_DATE, LIQ_METER_DELTASEC, LIQ_METER_PULSE, LIQ_METER_VALUE ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?  ) )


INSERT INTO LIQ_METER_VALUES ( LIQ_METER_SN, LIQ_METER_DATE, LIQ_METER_DELTASEC, LIQ_METER_PULSE, LIQ_METER_VALUE ) VALUES ( '12345', '08-08-2017', 10, 100, 500.0  ) )
```

Как вместо значений 100 и 500.0 использовать подзапрос SELECT? 
например такой

```
SELECT PULSE_CH1 FROM IMP_METER_VALUES WHERE IMP_METER_SN = '99999'
```

Т.е. результирующий запрос должнен выглядеть примерно так:

```
INSERT INTO LIQ_METER_VALUES ( LIQ_METER_SN, LIQ_METER_DATE, LIQ_METER_DELTASEC, LIQ_METER_PULSE, LIQ_METER_VALUE ) VALUES ( '12345', '08-08-2017', 10, (SELECT PULSE_CH1 FROM IMP_METER_VALUES WHERE IMP_METER_SN = '99999'), (SELECT PULSE_CH1 FROM IMP_METER_VALUES WHERE IMP_METER_SN = '99999')*5  ) )
```

Если такой запрос делать в базу отдельно QSqlQuery::exec("INSERT INTO..."), то все срабатывает, а если отправлять пачками QSqlQuery::execBatch(), то почему то подзапрос SELECT воспринимается как строка и не выполняется.

БД POSTGRESQL выдает ОШИБКА:  неверное значение для целого числа: ... (22P02) QPSQL: Unable to create query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это невозможно, prepared statements не поддерживают параметризацию подзапросами.

Comment: А есть ли альтернативные варианты? Дело в том, что я хочу одним и только одним  запросом к базе получить результат.  Я не хочу нагружать клиента вычислениями и множественными обращениями к базе, а хочу чтобы вычисления, сортировка и т. д. проводились на стороне сервера БД.

Comment: Конкатенация строк SQL-запросов. Но опасайтесь sql injection.

Comment: Т.е. мне необходимо сделать огромную строку запроса и отправить его не с помощью QSqlQuery::execBatch(), а с помощью QSqlQuery::exec()?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 0):

Если сам SELECT-запрос заранее известен, и отличаются лишь его параметры, то можно весь запрос хранить на сервере в виде функции. Параметры запроса передавать как параметры функции. На клиенте вызывать только хранимую функцию с нужными параметрами.